# Dropdown menu is dropping too low

Tags: html, css

Recently I fixed my dropdown menu which used to drop with all the other un-hovered buttons also changing their positions. The current issue I just noticed accidentally. When the page is all scrolled up, i.e. I am at starting position, dropdown works as expected. But if I scroll a little bit down, and then hover over button, the dropdown appears where it was before but I am expecting it to appear below the button. This is the snap of code I am using:

```css
.tut_navi_buttons .drop_down_navi_content {
  display: none;
  right: 0;
  position: unset;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  height: 0px;
  transition: height 1s ease;
}

.tut_navi_buttons:hover .drop_down_navi_content {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  /*height: auto;*/
  /*box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px grey;*/
}

#tut_navi {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
}

.tut_navi_buttons .drop_down_navi {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.tut_navi_buttons {
  width: auto;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  /*margin-bottom: 20px;*/
  /*padding: 5px;*/
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id='tut_navi'>
  <div class="tut_navi_buttons">
    <button class="drop_down_navi">Python Basics <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>
    <div class="drop_down_navi_content">
      <a href="tutorial1.html">Beginner</a>
      <a href="#">Pre-intermediate</a>
      <a href="#">Intermediate</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Please refer to the images I am attaching as they will make it clear.

[After scrolling a bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgSX5.png)

[While at top of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvtbx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Remove position:unset; replace with position:relative;
Separate the first two classes in the style sheet because it seems to be clashing